# Angular Http method not found

Tags: http, angular6

I've used this as core project for one of my project and I am stuck with it.
I trying to use the http method but it fails.
I've tried add the HttpClientModule to the app.module but still nothing.

The error that i get is :

```
app.ae014c5e7b696f87de83.bundle.js:107 ERROR TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'method' of undefined



All I did in the app.component.ts file add




  export class AppComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
      private readonly i18nStore: Store<I18NState>,
      private readonly config: ConfigService,
      private http: HttpClient,
      @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId: Object
  ) {
    super();
    // TODO: ngx-i18n-router
    // private readonly i18nRouter: I18NRouterService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.i18nStore.dispatch(new Init(this.config.getSettings('i18n')));
  }

  createUserA(): void  {
      this.http.get<any>('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
          .subscribe(data => console.log('data', data));
  }
}
```

Bot get and post don't work.
I've imported :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your **app.component.ts**

```
contructor(private http : HttpClient) {}
```